# What does the "Suggest" menu item do, on iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios

What does the "Suggest…" menu item do? I am referring to the one that comes straight after the "Paste" item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It suggests spelling corrections for the selected word.